# How can I stop a WCF Service from being recreated for each request?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a service that I need to run that manages long running background tasks. I am hosting this service through the WCF, but I'm running into a problem where the service keeps getting created and destroyed with every subsequent web request.

Here is the service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileProcessService 
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "ProcessFile?s={session}&file={fileName}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    int ProcessFile(int session, string fileName);
}

public class FileProcessService : IFileProcessService
{
    private FileProcessTaskScheduler mTaskScheduler;
    private TaskFactory mTaskFactory;

    private FileProcessService()
    {
        mTaskScheduler = new FileProcessTaskScheduler(4);
        mTaskFactory = new TaskFactory(mTaskScheduler);
    }

    public int ProcessFile(int scriptRunId, string fileName)
    {
        return mTaskFactory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processing file {0} for script run {1}", fileName, scriptRunId);
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
            Console.WriteLine("Completed processing file {0} for script run {1}", fileName, scriptRunId);
        }).Id;
    }
}
```

Obviously with the TaskScheduler and TaskFactory in there it doesn't really work when it gets disposed of at the end of every request.

Over in main I host the service like so:

```
WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(FileProcessService), new Uri("http://localhost:7343/"));
ServiceDebugBehavior sdb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
sdb.HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;

ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFileProcessService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");

host.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Service is now running...");
Console.ReadKey();
host.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Service has stopped...");
```

I have tried making the members of the service static and then just wrapping their instantiation in the constructor with if checks, but at that point I think it would just be cleaner to write a separate singleton class to handle that stuff.

The WCF WebServiceHost seems to refer to the instance of the service that it hosts as a singleton, but it certainly isn't treating it as such. Is there some extra step I have to take to make the WebServiceHost NOT dispose of my object after every request?

Comment: Use other constructor of `WebServiceHost` and pass the *instance* of your class not the *type*...

Comment: Set InstanceContextMode.Single in Service Behaviour.[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)] public class FileProcessService : IFileProcessService{}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [ServiceBehaviorAttribute InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can see a working example of this type of WCF service [here](https://github.com/Aelphaeis/MyWcfDuplexPipeExample/tree/MultiClient) and [this](https://github.com/Aelphaeis/MyWcfDuplexPipeExample/blob/MultiClient/MyWcfDuplexExample/MyService.cs) is where it's used in the code.

Comment: Also: A very good explanation is here http://www.remondo.net/wcf-servicebehavior-instancecontextmode-explained/ where OP should also investigate on Concurrency and perhaps Throttling